# Moving permissions to optional on chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I learned about Chrome disabling an extension when new permissions are added the hard way.

When I add new features to my extension I need to add new sites in the `permissions` list. Now I know I should have used `optional_permissions`.

My questions are:

1. If I move the site's list from `permissions` to `optional_permissions` does the user need to approve those sites again? or just the ones that I add over time.
2. Could any of these changes cause the extension to be disabled?:

   a. I add sites in the `matches` section of an entry in `content_scripts`

   b. I add sites in the `matches` section of an entry in `externally_connectable`
3. Is there a way to define `externally_connectable` in `optional_permissions`?

Related links: [chrome.permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) | [Permission Warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings)

---

**Update:** When Chrome disabled my extension I had added in the manifest one site on `content_scripts` > `matches` and `externally_connectable` with a `matches` site. The latter shows a new line in the permissions warnings saying `"Communicate with cooperating websites"`. I'm not sure which change caused the disabling, that's why I ask about `externally_connectable` too.

Comment: Did you try to [test permission warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#test) ?

Comment: @Deliaz No, but I definitely will before updating hosts again

Comment: I don't think testing it this way is possible anymore. One may need to add a test extension to the store.

Comment: @Xan is it possible to define test accounts for an already published extension or do I need to duplicate the extension for this tests?

Comment: To be on the safe side, I would use a fresh, unlisted extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to test **when extensions are disabled by Chrome** I created a private extension in the Chrome Web Store.

I started with a simple definition for `manifest.json` and then I added fields and settings one by one. For each test, I:

1. uploaded a new version to the store
2. waited for Google to publish the extension (this took a lot of time!)
3. forced the extension update on a testers' account
4. writed down the results

After **13 tests**, this is what I've found:

---

### Changes in `manifest` that DISABLE the extension

- Adding an entry at `"content_scripts"` > `"matches"` [Warning: "*Read and change your data on example.com*"]
- Adding `"externally_connectable"` > `{"ids", "matches"}` [Warning: "*Communicate with cooperating websites*"]

---

### Changes in `manifest` that did NOT disabled the extension (no warnings)

- Adding `"declarativeContent"` permission
- Adding `"optional_permissions"` > all hosts
- Adding an entry at `"externally_connectable"` > `"ids"` (after `externally_connectable` was accepted)
- Adding an entry at `"externally_connectable"` > `"matches"` (after `externally_connectable` was accepted)
- Adding an entry of a host without permissions at `"externally_connectable"` > `"matches"` (after `externally_connectable` was accepted)
- Adding `"incognito": "split"`
- Adding `"content_security_policy"` > script-src URL
- Adding `"web_accessible_resources"`

Plus, permissions listed at [permission_warnings#nowarning](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#nowarning) docs.

I probably did some silly tests like `"web_accessible_resources"`, but I prefer that than having Chrome disabling my extension again.

---

### Special test

Since I'm moving to `optional_permissions`, all hosts listed in `permissions` are removed. So, I wanted to know what would happen with the disabled extension when a new update does not have the problematic permission anymore:

Update 1: a new host is added at `"content_scripts"` > `"matches"` => Extension disabled

Update 2: the problematic host is removed from `"content_scripts"` => **Extension ENABLED again**

To conclude, **if you made a mistake you can release a new version rolling back the changes that caused the extension to be disabled**.

> If I move the site's list from `permissions` to `optional_permissions` does the user need to approve those sites again? or just the ones that I add over time.

The answer is straightforward, no. Chrome stores all permissions given to the extension over time. So, only the new hosts on `optional_permissions` need to be approved.

Comment: This is a great insight, Thank you very much for taking time and sharing the behaviors.

Comment: Did anyone tested "storage" permission and can tell if that would cause the extension to be disabled? (Hope to avoid waiting for test extension review in CWS)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If I move the site's list from permissions to optional_permissions does the user need to approve those sites again? or just the ones that I add over time.

New users: yes, they will need to approve it.

Existing installs that get updated: most likely no.

Consider: even if you completely remove a permission, and then put it back again, it is still considered granted.

The general documentation quote is: "Chrome prompts the user if adding the permissions results in different warning messages than the user has already seen and accepted."

> 2. Could any of these changes cause the extension to be disabled?:
>
>    a. I add sites in the `matches` section of an entry in `content_scripts`
>
>    b. I add sites in the `matches` section of an entry in `externally_connectable`

a. Adding matches to `content_scripts` is equivalent to giving full host permissions and will cause your extension to be disabled if it's a new host. If you already had host permissions for that host, it will not be disabled.

b. I don't know. In theory, this does not grant your extension any new permissions, so it shouldn't.

> 3. Is there a way to define externally_connectable in optional_permissions?

As per docs, no. It's not a permission to begin with.

Comment: regarding 2.a., is there any way to add a new host on `content_scripts` > `matches` without causing the extension to be disabled? If I use "http://*/" on `optional_permission` and ask for that new host permission at runtime, will the extension still be disabled?

Comment: The point of asking at runtime is to avoid being disabled; but if you add a content script match it's a non-optional host permission. If you want to use content scripts with optional permissions, you'll have to programmatically inject.

Comment: so, instead of adding a `content_scripts`, I add a permission for a site and inject the same files as before. I guess I will have to simulate the `document_end` too, not sure how to solve the `"all_frames"`

Comment: Read the docs of `chrome.tabs.executeScript` - it takes a lot of optional parameters that duplicate manifest keys.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I can see the corresponding parameters

Comment: I'm in the middle of the move to optional permissions and I've found a dead end. If you want a challenge, check [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44425102/1718678)